# Dataframe iteration does not increment variable

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iteration

I have been going around in loops (ironically) trying to get a snip of code to iterate over each row of a data frame.
If I perform a single row condition, the result is what I need, however as soon as I try to iterate, it stops working.

So, here is the snippet of code:

```
i = 1
j = 100
if (i < j):
    htref = new_resultsdf.iloc[0, 1]
    validornot = home_form_5.loc[(home_form_5.iloc[:, 0] == htref) & (home_form_5['scored'] > 6) & (home_form_5['conceeded'] > 6) & (home_form_5['CScount'] < 2) & (home_form_5['DNScount'] < 2) & (home_form_5['o1.5Count'] > 3)].all() == 1
    answer = validornot.all()
    if answer == True:
        new_resultsdf.iloc[0, 23] = 'Yes'
        validfixturedf = new_resultsdf[(new_resultsdf['Valid'].isin(['Yes']))]
    else:
        new_resultsdf.iloc[0, 23] = 'Nope'
        notvalidfixturedf = new_resultsdf[(new_resultsdf['Valid'].isin(['Nope']))]
    new_resultsdf = new_resultsdf.loc[new_resultsdf['Valid'] == 'pending']
    new_resultsdf.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    i = (i+1)
else:
    call_ref = len(new_resultsdf.index)
    call_ref
```

call_ref starts at 280 (*note that j = 100 here because I just wanted to test a smaller sample first*). I have it after 'else', not because I think I need it but so I could see the length of the dataframe and if it had worked.

I can make call_ref go down in increments of 1 if I remove:

```
i = 1
    j = 100
    if (i < j):
```

and the last 'else'

When I add it back in, 'i' increments by 1 to 2, but that's it. Just 1 loop!

I do appreciate there is likely a more pythonic way to do this and I have looked into various other ways, however because I need to perform an action on the **first** row only for each iteration, I could not find a suitable way to do this.

To give more detail, the 'new_resultsdf' is German Liga3 football results.

For the first row **only** and until there are no more rows, I want to look at the home team 'htref' and use 'htref' to look up a form dataframe, 'home_form_5'.
If conditions are met, the 'Valid' column entry is changed from 'pending' to 'Yes', otherwise it's changed to 'Nope'.

```
htref = new_resultsdf.iloc[0, 1]
validornot = home_form_5.loc[(home_form_5.iloc[:, 0] == htref) & (home_form_5['scored'] > 6) & (home_form_5['conceeded'] > 6) & (home_form_5['CScount'] < 2) & (home_form_5['DNScount'] < 2) & (home_form_5['o1.5Count'] > 3)].all() == 1
answer = validornot.all()
if answer == True:
    new_resultsdf.iloc[0, 23] = 'Yes'
    validfixturedf = new_resultsdf[(new_resultsdf['Valid'].isin(['Yes']))]
else:
    new_resultsdf.iloc[0, 23] = 'Nope'
    notvalidfixturedf = new_resultsdf[(new_resultsdf['Valid'].isin(['Nope']))]
```

That first row is placed in a 'validfixturedf' or 'notvalidfixturedf' and removed from 'new_resultsdf' by taking only the rows with 'pending' in the 'Valid' column.

```
new_resultsdf = new_resultsdf.loc[new_resultsdf['Valid'] == 'pending']
```

*Ultimately I need 'home_form_5' to be dynamic and update after each iteration, however as I'm taking this is steps, I wanted to get the interation on 'new_resultsdf' working first.*

What I would have expected is that 'i' would be increment up to 'j' and the iteration would stop. What I am finding is that 'i' increments to 2 only.

This has stumped me for some time now, partly because I have read about not looping over dataframes and that leading me to try different solutions, however this solution is the only one I have tried which kind of works - it works if I iterate 1 row at a time by running the code without the 'i < j' lines.

Comment: You have to use `while (i < j):` instead of  `if..` to have a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop to have iterations with the

`while(i<j):
    #your code
    i += 1`

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while